# Mongod not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I keep getting this response when trying to run a node app with a MongoDB

```
body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares server.js:32:9
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option node_modules/body-parser/index.js:105:29
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option server.js:35:9
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option server.js:35:9
Running on3000

/Users/tvc/Desktop/SupperClubApp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^`

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
```

I am unsure as to how to resolve it. Any tips much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please rethink the wording of your title to be more descriptive of your problem, and please also include the code you are at least using to connect. Also basic working out if the `mongod` daemon is even running at all before launching into stack errors would be very helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure I do not have it running already but when I run mongod I get this error

Comment: > 2015-10-06T09:50:54.164+0100 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty. 2015-10-06T09:50:54.164+0100 D -        [initandlisten] User Assertion: 98:Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?
 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating 2015-10-06T09:50:54.164+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Analysis:** 
the issue as per the exception that you copied in the comments says that you Mongodb connection could not be established as there was an issue with Mongodb connection close the previous time. Mongodb will encounter this issue when your computer was forceshutdown due to power outages and other issues. 
**the exception content from your comments is as below:**
`[initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty. 2015-10-06T09:50:54.164+0100 D - [initandlisten] User Assertion: 98:Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?`
**Investigation:**
Check if there is a file named `Mongod.lock` got created in your `\bin` folder.
**Solution:**
If the size of the file `Mongod.lock` is greater than 0KB, please delete the file and re run your mongodb. It should work fine. [More details at this link](http://eshwartechtalks.blogspot.com/2014/10/mongodb-issues-recover-data-after.html)

Comment: Thank you Eshwar, that is really helpful, I shall follow your instructions now and hope to get this up ad running again asap.

Comment: @tvc25, if it has resolved your issue, can you comeback and mark this as answer so that it will benefit a lot more developers like us in the future?